# SSL = Cannot create certificate for IIS (Cannot create PFX file from KEY+Certificate+RootCa)

Tags: iis, ssl, openssl, crt, cer

I just got 4 files from RapidSSL which I would like to use for IIS Express.
To do this I need to create a PFX file.

I have CSR, KEY, CERTIFICATE, ROOT/CA. Here there are:

CSR => I saved it as CSR.csr

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
... hidden :)
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

KEY -> I saved is as key.pem

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
... hidden :)
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Certificate -> I saved is as cert.cer

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... hidden :)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Root/CA -> I saved is as CA.cer

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... hidden :)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I tried this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey key.pem -in cert.crt -export -out cert_pfx.pfx
```

Loading 'screen' into random state - done 
No certificate matches private key

I have also tried this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert_pfx.pfx -inkey key.pem -in cert.crt -certfile CA.crt
```

The same error here.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://support.servertastic.com/convert-pem-to-pfx/

Make sure the Private Key does sign the actual certificate. If it is a RapidSSL it might be worth re-issuing the certificate again to make sure the certificate is correct. You can do this free of charge here: https://products.geotrust.com/orders/orderinformation/authentication.do